# GTK+2でのダイアログのカスタマイズ方法

Tags: c, gtk

GTK+1で組まれたプログラムをGTK+2に移行しようとしています。
元のプログラムの中で、フォント選択ダイアログをカスタマイズして表示している部分があるのですが、同様の事はGTK+2でも可能でしょうか？

カスタマイズの内容としては、例えばフォントサイズのリスト部分を自前のリストに置換えたり、他一部部品を非表示にしたりというような事です。
元のプログラムではダイアログを構成する部品をGtkFontSelectionのmain_vboxメンバから辿っていじれたのですが、GTK+2でどのようにすれば実現できるのかまだ方法を見つけられていません。

ヒントでも良いのでアドバイスいただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えば以下のようにすると、family list を非表示にできます。

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void print_hier(int indent, GtkWidget *w)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < indent * 2; i++)
        putchar(' ');
    printf("%p %s\n", w, g_type_name(((GTypeInstance *)w)->g_class->g_type));
    if (GTK_IS_CONTAINER(w)) {
        GList *children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(w));
        GList *p;
        for (p = children; p != NULL; p = g_list_next(p))
            print_hier(indent + 1, p->data);
    }
}

static void hide_family_list(GtkWidget *sel)
{
    print_hier(0, sel);

    GtkWidget *tbl = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(sel))->data;
    GtkWidget *scrl = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(tbl))->next->next->data;
    gtk_widget_hide(scrl);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_font_selection_dialog_new("font selection");

    GtkWidget *fontsel = gtk_font_selection_dialog_get_font_selection(GTK_FONT_SELECTION_DIALOG(dialog));
    hide_family_list(fontsel);

    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));

    return 0;
}
```

widget の階層構造を表示する print_hier() を付けておきました。
いじる際にはこの出力が参考になると思います。

Comment: 参考になります。
ただこのコードを試してみようと思ったのですが、gtk_font_selection_dialog_get_font_selection()の宣言が私の環境では見つかりませんでした。
使用しようとしているのはGTK+2.0なんですが、バージョンが低過ぎるでしょうか。

ちなみに、その関数の代わりに"GTK_DIALOG(dialog)->vbox"の値を使ってみたら、一応出力はできたものの最後のscrlを取得する箇所でコアダンプしてしまいました。

Comment: 補足というか訂正です。
"fontsel"を"GTK_FONT_SELECTION_DIALOG(dialog)->fontsel"で取得したところ、正常に動作することを確認できました。  
(前のdialog->vboxとしたのは、[GITORIUS](https://www.gitorious.org/gnome/gtk/source/bf573a1e1ef913e309ffcab1feb4bc5ee8da1a3d:gtk/gtkfontsel.h)でのコメント文を見てでしたが、あらためて自環境のファイルを見てみたらGSEALが付いていなかったり違いが見られました）

Comment: すみません、バージョンを書き忘れました。2.24.25 です。

Comment: とりあえず見た目を同じような感じには変える事ができました。
これで先に進める事ができます。ありがとうございました。